# Sharepoint: How to add audience filter to custom control?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, filter, controls, audience

In MOSS 2007 I want to add a custom control to the global link section of a master page and have it only visible to a particular audience.

The audience are the members of an active directory group who have logged in via SSL and need to be given a link which will log them out.

How can I filter a custom control so that only these users will see it? Is there an API or something like `Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl` which might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is an API for audiences. Here are some links from MSDN to get you started:

- [Audiences Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms571011.aspx)
- [Audience Object Model Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms567140.aspx)
- [Targeting Content Using Audiences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497910.aspx) (several how-tos and code samples)

I haven't come across a security trimmed control for audiences but it should be fairly easy to write one.